# iOS - Trigger Notification Service Extension through Local Push Notification?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, extension-methods, local

> Is it possible to trigger **Notification Service Extension** through **Local Push Notification?**

My code snippet

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()

// Adding title,subtitle,body & badge
content.title = "title"
content.body = "body"
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

let aps = ["mutable-content": 1]
let dict = ["aps": aps, "some-key": "some-value"] as [AnyHashable : Any]
content.userInfo = dict

let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 10, repeats: false)
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "SimplifiedIOSNotification", content: content as UNNotificationContent, trigger: trigger)
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: Have you tested this to see if it's possible or are you just asking here first?

Comment: yes tested this as well as remote push, it's working only with remote push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, It is not possible to trigger notification service extension through push notification.

**Reason:** `Service extension lets you customize the content of a remote notification before it is delivered to the user. e.g decrypt the message or download the attachments`

but I personally think there is no point of downloading the notification content attachments in service extension because you can always download the attachments before scheduling. e.g

```
    // Download attachment asynchronously 
    downloadAttachments(data: data) { attachments in
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    // Add downloaded attachment here
    content.attachments = attachments

    // Adding title,subtitle,body & badge
    content.title = "title"
    content.body = "body"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

    // No need of adding mutable content here
    let dict = ["some-key": "some-value"] as [AnyHashable : Any]
    content.userInfo = dict

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 10, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "SimplifiedIOSNotification", content: content as UNNotificationContent, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
    }
```

Let me know if you have different use case.

Answer (score -1):

Pleas read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension) before posting. The first line states:

> A UNNotificationServiceExtension object provides the entry point for a Notification Service app extension, which lets you customize the content of a **remote notification** before it is delivered to the user.